# Automatically rearranging GridView items

Tags: android, gridview

I am currently working on a project and i am using a GridView. I wanted to know if it is possible to rearrange items in a GridView based ranging from the "most clicked" item to the "least clicked" item.

Thank you,

Comment: yes it is possible but it depends on your logic... if you stuck somewhere please share the code. it would be easy to help you

Comment: please, how will that be possible. Can i have some code snippets or something like that? Thank you.

Comment: you want to save it permanently or just to want to change items at runtime?

Comment: permanently and constantly changing as the values change.

Comment: okay i'll add the answer in morning.. now i am going to sleep.  its 5:00Am here.

Comment: @MustanserIqbal i am still waiting for your response. thank you

Comment: ohhh sorry bro. i just forgot ithat. sorry for that.. now i am away.. i'll be home after 2-3 hour and then i'll write code for you. sorry for the delay man.

Comment: demo app is ready for you. will upload it in the morning... please wait. :)

Comment: did you check my answer?

Comment: Yeah. i checked it last night.

Comment: so did you find it helpful? is that's what you was looking for?

Comment: yes, sure it was very helpful. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for the delay here is the code to rearrange items on click.
i hope that will satisfy you need.

ExampleData.java file.

```
package com.example;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Comparator;

/**
 * Created by Mustanser Iqbal on 2/6/2015.
 */

public class ExampleData implements Serializable {

    private String name;
    private String title;
    int itemCount;

    public ExampleData(String title,String name,int itemCount) {
        this.name = name;
        this.title = title;
        this.itemCount = itemCount;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public int getItemCount() {
        return itemCount;
    }

    public void setItemCount(int itemCount) {
        this.itemCount = itemCount;
    }


    // Comparator
    public static class RearrangeData implements Comparator<ExampleData> {
        @Override
        public int compare(ExampleData arg0, ExampleData arg1) {
            return arg0.itemCount - arg1.itemCount;
        }
    }
}
```

ExampleAdapter.java file

```
package com.example;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;

/**
 * Created by Mustanser Iqbal on 2/6/2016.
 */
public class ExampleAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private ArrayList<ExampleData> mExampleData;
    private Context mContext;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;

    public ExampleAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<ExampleData> mExample) {
        this.mContext = context;
        this.mExampleData = mExample;
        this.inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mExampleData.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return mExampleData.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {

            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_item, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.titleTextView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.title);
            holder.nameTextView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.name);
            holder.countTextView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.count);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        holder.titleTextView.setText(mExampleData.get(position).getTitle());

        holder.nameTextView.setText(mExampleData.get(position).getName());
        holder.countTextView.setText(""+mExampleData.get(position).getItemCount());

        convertView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mExampleData.get(position).setItemCount((mExampleData.get(position).getItemCount()+1));
                Collections.sort(mExampleData, new ExampleData.RearrangeData());
                Collections.reverse(mExampleData);
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
        return convertView;
    }

    public class ViewHolder {
        TextView titleTextView, nameTextView, countTextView;
    }
}
```

MainActivity .java file

```
package com.example;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;

/**
 * Created by Mustanser Iqbal on 2/6/2016.
 */
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ExampleAdapter mExampleAdapter;
    private ArrayList<ExampleData> exampleDataArrayList;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.header);

        TextView actionBarText = (TextView) toolbar.findViewById(R.id.toolbar_title);
        actionBarText.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.title));
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        try {
            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        // i Assume that this data is coming from server. or anywhere else.

        exampleDataArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
        exampleDataArrayList.add(new ExampleData("Mobile", "Android", 3));
        exampleDataArrayList.add(new ExampleData("Mobile", "iPhone", 6));
        exampleDataArrayList.add(new ExampleData("Mobile", "BlackBarry", 7));
        exampleDataArrayList.add(new ExampleData("Mobile", "Windows", 9));
        exampleDataArrayList.add(new ExampleData("Mobile", "Sony", 2));
        exampleDataArrayList.add(new ExampleData("Laptop", "HP", 5));
        exampleDataArrayList.add(new ExampleData("Laptop Charger", "XYZ Comapny", 8));

        Collections.sort(exampleDataArrayList, new ExampleData.RearrangeData());
        Collections.reverse(exampleDataArrayList);

        GridView gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView);
        mExampleAdapter = new ExampleAdapter(this, exampleDataArrayList);
        gridView.setAdapter(mExampleAdapter);

    }

}
```

action_bar.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar_top"
    style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/bg_color"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textColor="@color/header_text_color"
        android:text="" />


</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

activity_main.xml file

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <include android:id="@+id/header"
        layout="@layout/action_bar"/>

    <GridView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/header"
        android:id="@+id/gridView"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        android:clipToPadding="true"
        android:columnWidth="150dp"
        android:numColumns="2"
        android:verticalSpacing="2dp"
        android:horizontalSpacing="2dp"
        android:fastScrollEnabled="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:gravity="center"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

grid_item.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:layout_margin="2dp"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_green_dark">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:text=""
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text=""
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:gravity="start"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/title"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/count"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text=""
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/title"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

colors.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="bg_color">#686d77</color>
    <color name="header_text_color">#64B5F6</color>
    <color name="header_text_color_selected">#95caf4</color>
</resources>
```

strings.xml

```
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">Rearrange GridItems</string>
       <string name="title">ReArrange GridItems Example</string>
</resources>
```

styles.xml

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    </style>

</resources>
```

Comment: thanks man. It works great, but is there a way to save the state of the activity when the user exits the application, in such a way that the order in which the items are arranged when the user exits is the same when the user re-opens the app

Comment: yes it is possible.. there are many ways to do this. one is you can store the data in data in SQL lite or on any server. the other way is store the arraylist in sharedpreference  when you exit the app. it your choice what you want.

Comment: ok. thanks, that's what i was going for, but i think for simplicity sake, i will go with SharedPreferences

Comment: yeah i think that would be more easy than sql. Best of Luck Happy Coding